# Getting old ouput from Terraform@1.3.7 apply command after changing structure of Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I had old Terraform configuration, worked perfect.
In short, I had static website application I needed to deploy using Cloudfront & S3. Then, I need another application to deploy in the same way, but in other sub-domain.

For ease of helping, you can check the full source code here:

Old Terraform configuration: https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-old

New Terraform configuration: https://github.com/tal-rofe/tf-new

So, my domain is `example.io`, and in the old configuration I had only static application deployed on `app.example.com`.
But, as I need an another application, it's going to be deployed on `docs.example.com`.
To avoid a lot of code duplication, I decided on creating a local module for deploying a generic application onto Cloudfront & S3.
After doing so, seems like `terraform apply` and `terraform plan` succeeds (not really, as no resources were changed at all!): `Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.`

Not only no changes, but I get an old output:

```
cloudfront_distribution_id = "blabla"
eks_kubeconfig = <sensitive>
```

This `cloudfront_distribution_id` output, was the correct output using the old configuration. I expect to get these new outputs, as configured:

```
output "frontend_cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  description = "The distribution ID of deployed Cloudfront frontend"
  value       = module.frontend-static.cloudfront_distribution_id
}

output "docs_cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  description = "The distribution ID of deployed Cloudfront docs"
  value       = module.docs-static.cloudfront_distribution_id
}

output "eks_kubeconfig" {
  description = "EKS Kubeconfig content"
  value       = module.eks-kubeconfig.kubeconfig
  sensitive   = true
}
```

I'm using GitHub actions to apply my Terraform configuration with these steps:

```yaml
            - name: Terraform setup
              uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
              with:
                terraform_wrapper: false

            - name: Terraform core init
              env:
                  TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET }}
                  TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE }}
              run: |
                terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" init \
                -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_BACKEND_S3_BUCKET" \
                -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TERRAFORM_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE" \
                -backend-config="region=$AWS_REGION"
                
            - name: Terraform core plan
              run: terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" plan -no-color -out state.tfplan

            - name: Terraform core apply
              run: terraform -chdir="./terraform/core" apply state.tfplan
```

I used the same steps in my old & new Terraform configurations.
I want to re-use the logic written in my `static-app` module twice. So basically I want to be able to create static application just by using the module I've configured.

Comment: Which version of terraform are you using?

Comment: @MarkoE Im using version `"1.3.7"`

Comment: Are you sure that the latest version of the module is downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define the outputs in the root module and expect it to work because you are already using a different module in your `static-app` module (i.e., you are nesting modules). Since you are using the terraform module there (denoted with `source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"`) you are limited to what that [module provides as outputs](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudfront/blob/master/outputs.tf) and hence can only define those outputs on the module level, not root level. I see you are referencing the EKS output works, but the difference here is that that particular module is not nested and is called directly (from your repo):

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.5.1"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The way I would suggest fixing this is to call the Cloudfront module from the root module (i.e., `core` in your example):

```
module "frontend-static" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"
  version = "3.1.0"

 ... rest of the configuration ...

}

module "docs-static" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"
  version = "3.1.0"

 ... rest of the configuration ...

}
```

The outputs you currently have defined in your repo with new configuration (`tf-new`) should work out-of-the-box with this change. Alternatively, you could write your own module and then you can control which outputs you will have.

Comment: If I create the cloudfront module in the `core` I lose all the concept of isolation. I don't understand - I did write my own module.. this `static-app` module.. How can I then re-use it and still have the outputs I wanted?

Comment: You haven't written it, you are using an existing one that someone else created. You just moved it into a separate directory. It is the same concept you are using for EKS, i.e., in the `eks.tf` file. The above answer will work but if that's not what you want, that's a different problem altogether.

Comment: So there is no way of writing my own module while using other module within?

Comment: There is of course, but not the way you are currently trying to do. I responded to the initial problem that was laid out in your question.

Comment: Well, I wish to create such a module, so I can re-use it in my `core` folder. Could you please refer for that issue? I'd edit my question if required, I thought it was clear

Comment: That would be completely different question then which would render my answer useless.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will post other question.